# Creating polygon layers showing parking zones in particular area using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, power-bi

So I'd like to create a Shapefile map which constitutes of the various 'Controlled Parking Zones(CPZ)' within the London Borough of Southwark. The map I'd like to create would be comprised of polygons similar to a map which shows various wards/municipalities. Like the image seen below:

[image: Map]

The various parking zones within the borough can be found here:

https://www.southwark.gov.uk/parking/find-somewhere-to-park/parking-zones

Alternatively, here is an image of it:

[image: Image showing the CPZ zones in Southwark Council]

Ultimately, what I'd like to be able to do is import the shapefile into Power BI. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can tackle this?

Comment: Apologies. One first needs to convert the shapefile into a topoJSON file using mapshaper and then import that json file into PowerBI.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Georeference](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html?highlight=georeferencing) the image you have
2. [Create a polygon layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/create_new_vector.html) and digitize the zones with your gereferenced image in the background

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am new to QGIS, but I would give step 1 a try. Out of curiosity assuming I don't have an image to trace over how can I create the zones then? So assume all we know is the road boundaries.

Comment: (You have the image in your question). If you know the roads it it easier, add a basemap to QGIS, create the polygon layer and digitize. If you dont have any basemaps you can add many using [this python script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py) and they can be found in Browser-XYZ tiles

Comment: I understand. Yes I've installed a few maps already using a plugin. I'll follow both methods you've provided as I'm keen to learn how they work. Thank you.